# CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe has stopped working

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I have CefSharp-master project with which is Built on Chromium- 31.0.1650.57. All is working fine and perfect, but when I click on link to load/view PDF file on an website and popup get loaded and after some time I got dialog box saying **"CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe has stopped working."** and oped popup window become black. Below is what I found in windows event viewer..

```
Application: CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException
Stack:
   at <Module>.CefExecuteProcess(CefMainArgs*, CefRefPtr<CefApp>*)
   at CefSharp.CefAppWrapper.Run(System.String[])
   at CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.Program.Main(System.String[])
```

What is problem? I searched a lot but didn't find any think.

Comment: Please add information on if you are using WPF or WinForms above. Currently we're guessing WPF. It would be good to actually *know*

Answer (score 1):

I think you actually are being hit by two different issues:

1. The Adobe PDF plugin not working with off-screen rendering which is what is used by the `CefSharp.Wpf` component. See screenshot of `CefSharp.Wpf.Example` below.

   Short term the PDF plugin works with `CefSharp.WinForms` which I just tried out with the master branch. Longer term I hope the fact that Google donated the Crome PDF support to Chromium and thus in time CEF and CefSharp will remove the dependency on the Adobe PDF plugin.
2. The crash I suspect to be due to that the site you are at opens the PDF in a new window. That's a bug that apparently got introduced in master between the v.31.0.0-pre1 release and now. Please check if the [#449 PR](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/pull/449) resolves your crashes issue, and report back over there.

The term "off-screen rendering" - or the enthusiast version, OSR even, is explained at https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/wiki/GeneralUsage#Off-Screen_Rendering. In general I recommend reading up a little on CEF as well if you are using CefSharp and the General Usage wiki page is a good place to start.

CefSharp uses CEF's OSR mode for WPF and normal/non-OSR mode for WinForms.

[image: Here you see the PDF plugin giving a blank screen with WPF rendering depend on the Adobe Plugin (but I get no crash)]

Comment: Ah, ok then in your case you can forget about the OSR part of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Adobe Acrobat pdf plugin crashed. That plugin won't work correctly in off-screen rendering mode. See this topic on CEF Forum:

http://www.magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=11440

You can disable specific plugins in CefRequestHandler::OnBeforePluginLoad:

https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/search?q=OnBeforePluginLoad&ref=cmdform

Comment: Your provided links will help me, but disableing PDF plugins will not solve my problem. I tired with lower version (25) of CefSharp works fine with pdf viewer, whats the probelm with 31 version, am I missing some references? And sorry to ask such a small question but What is off-screen rendering mode?, I didn't get it.